# WARNING:tensorflow: Please switch to tf.summary.scalar. Note that tf.summary.scalar uses the node name instead of the tag

Tags: tensorflow

following codes from tensorflow get_started

[Getting Started With TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started)

when I running with Pycharm, much warning will be appear, setting the environment variable TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL to 2 or 3 isn't work;

**IDE:** PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1
Build #PC-171.3780.115, built on March 24, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b13 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.4.0-62-generic

**System:** Linux Muse 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**tensorflow:** 1.1.0-rc0 with Anaconda Python 3.6.0

I just want to close this warning or anther other method can fixed it, it is boring.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
features = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("x", dimension=1)]
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=features)
x = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
y = np.array([0., -1., -2., -3.])
input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x":x}, y, batch_size=4, 
num_epochs=1000)
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)
print(estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn))
```

WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: /tmp/tmpr_l0viod

WARNING:tensorflow:Rank of input Tensor (1) should be the same as output_rank (2) for column. Will attempt to expand dims. It is highly recommended that you resize your input, as this behavior may change.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/zhengql/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/head.py:615: scalar_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-11-30.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.summary.scalar. Note that tf.summary.scalar uses the node name instead of the tag. This means that TensorFlow will automatically de-duplicate summary names based on the scope they are created in. Also, passing a tensor or list of tags to a scalar summary op is no longer supported.

WARNING:tensorflow:Rank of input Tensor (1) should be the same as output_rank (2) for column. Will attempt to expand dims. It is highly recommended that you resize your input, as this behavior may change.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/zhengql/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/head.py:615: scalar_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-11-30.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.summary.scalar. Note that tf.summary.scalar uses the node name instead of the tag. This means that TensorFlow will automatically de-duplicate summary names based on the scope they are created in. Also, passing a tensor or list of tags to a scalar summary op is no longer supported.

WARNING:tensorflow:Skipping summary for global_step, must be a float or np.float32.
{'loss': 2.1558171e-07, 'global_step': 1000}